# How to deploy a reddit app written in python on Digitalocean?

Tags: python, digital-ocean

I made a reddit bot that needs to monitor a subreddit without a break. I want to deploy this bot on a VPS using Digitalocean. How do I go about it? All the instructions/tutorials found are for Flask and Django.

Comment: your app is made in Flask? state that clearly

Comment: No, it doesn't. It uses the PRAW framework. It's a reddit app.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What exactly do you need to "deploy"? DigitalOcean is just a supplier of VPSs, you configure them exactly like you would any other server.

Comment: I meant run it on their server. I've never done this before, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: You can checkout http://www.heroku.com

Comment: I do not want to use heroku, as I have a coupon for Digitalocean. I'll have to pay $7/month if I use Heroku, because I can't have my app go to sleep for 6 hours everyday.

Comment: So its just a script?

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer, yes, it's just a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume its just a Python Script / Programm and you want to run it as a service.

This can be done using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).
Install it via package or pip and create a file like this in the `supervisord/conf/` dir.

```
[program:bot]
command = /path/to/bot                    ; Command to start app
user = hello                                                          ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /path/to/logs/bot.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8                       ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

Start `supervisord` - eg sudo service supervisord start;
The you start your programm with `supervisorctl start bot` and supervisor will run like a service.

Comment: My script involves data persistence. Will I be able to do that if I run my script on supervisor?

Comment: Supervisor will run your script and give you an interface like for starting/stoping and restarting the script. The script will not be affected. Speaking about data persistence - it depends how you handle it in your script. If you store your data in a file it will be stored there. If you have the data in your memory it will be keept as long as the script is running.

Comment: I do store it in a file, so the data will persist even across multiple runs?

Comment: Yes the files will be there across multiple runs - well depending on how you handle it in your script

Comment: Excellent. That you, I'll check it out.